# Pandas data frames margins by arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I have to data frames and I need to combine both to get a new one where certain elements from the first (`df1`) will be inserted into the second one (`df2`).

For example:

```
df1=
        event_id    entity_type start_i end_i          token_name   doc_id
    0         T1           Drug   10756 10766          amiodarone   114220
    1         T2           Drug   14597 14614   Calcium Carbonate   114220
    2         T3       Strength   14615 14621              500 mg   114220
    3         T4           Form   14622 14638              Tablet   114220
```

and the second data frame:

```
df2 = 

    event_id    relation_type   arg_1   arg_2   doc_id
235       R1    Strength-Drug      T3      T2   114220
236       R2    Form-Drug          T4      T2   114220
```

and I need to get the combined data frame:

```
df3 = 

    event_id    relation_type    arg_1              arg_2   doc_id
235       R1    Strength-Drug   500 mg  Calcium Carbonate   114220
236       R2    Form-Drug       Tablet  Calcium Carbonate   114220
```

Basically, what happens here is the substitution of `arg_1` and `arg_2` in `df2` specified by `Ti` and `Tj` by `token_name` based on its `event_id` which are `Ti` and `Tj` in `df1`.

```
df3 = df2.copy()

df3.loc[235,'arg_1'] = df1.loc[df1.event_id == df2.loc[235,'arg_1'], 'token_name'].iloc[0]
df3.loc[235,'arg_2'] = df1.loc[df1.event_id == df2.loc[235,'arg_2'], 'token_name'].iloc[0]
df3.loc[236,'arg_1'] = df1.loc[df1.event_id == df2.loc[236,'arg_1'], 'token_name'].iloc[0]
df3.loc[236,'arg_2'] = df1.loc[df1.event_id == df2.loc[236,'arg_2'], 'token_name'].iloc[0]
```

I have 'quick-and-dirty' implementation, which works fine, but very slow and given the large number of documents, it is infeasible.

Any ideas for proper implementation with Pandas? It should be a tricky combination of pd.join / pd.merge but I'm still working to figure out which one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with `dictionary` created by `zip`:

```
d = dict(zip(df1['event_id'], df1['token_name']))
#alternative
#d = df1.set_index('event_id')['token_name']

cols = ['arg_1','arg_2']
#not exist values are set to NaN
df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(lambda x: x.map(d))
#alternative - not exist values are not changed
#df2[cols] = df2[cols].replace(d)
print (df2)
    event_id  relation_type   arg_1              arg_2  doc_id
235       R1  Strength-Drug  500 mg  Calcium Carbonate  114220
236       R2      Form-Drug  Tablet  Calcium Carbonate  114220
```